# Pipline Object to Measure-Object and keep the object

Tags: powershell

how can it be showing the directory with the sum ,
Code show only the sum property without the name of the directory [object]

the code:

```
dir -Directory | foreach {dir $PSItem | Measure-Object -Sum Length }  | Sort-Object -Property Sum -Descending
```

the output:

```
Count    : 35
Average  : 
Sum      : 90665167100
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : Length

Count    : 330
Average  : 
Sum      : 562853107
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : Length
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select-Object does the job.  Have to save $_ or $PSItem to a $dir variable because it changes.

```
Get-Childitem -Directory | 
Foreach-Object { 
  $dir = $_
  Get-Childitem $_ | 
  Measure-Object -Sum Length |
  Select-Object @{Name='dir';Expression={$dir}}, Sum 
} | 
Sort-Object -Property Sum -Descending

dir  Sum
---  ---
foo1  10
```

Comment: Instead of a foreach directly do the Measure inside the calculated property of the Select-Object `Get-ChildItem -Directory|Select-Object FullName,@{n='Sum';e={(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -file|Measure-Object Length -S
um).Sum}}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you only want to show the value of `SUM`?

```
dir -Directory | foreach { (dir $PSItem | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum  }
```

This will only output the value for um per directory.

Comment: the directory name with the sum